# my application doesn't respond with orientation of ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, window, orientation

when I rotate ipad my application didn't rotate i enabled all orientations and i add them to .plist file but still not respond and I didn't found

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    return YES;

}
```

on my application and i don't now where i should put it 
my application details :
MainWindow.xib:
its file owner class is UIApplication in placeholder
and in objects : App Controller its class is App Controller
& Painting Window its class is PaintingWindow
& Painting View its class is PaintingView

and i have AppController.h and .m

```
 @interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

and I have PaintingWindow.h and .m

```
@interface PaintingWindow : UIWindow
```

and I have PaintingView.h and .m

```
@interface PaintingView : UIView
```

where should i put this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is a UIViewController method, so you need to have a subclass of UIViewController to put it in.

Comment: No, you have to implement that method in a UIViewController or a subclass. You should have a view controller whose view is PaintingView if that's the view you want to rotate.